# generating cyclomatic complexity graphs

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, cyclomatic-complexity

(Before marking this as duplicate I have searched a lot and not found what I am looking for)

A tool that generates control flow graphs from **java** source code.
Which would then allow me to calculate cyclomatic complexity.
(I don't mind if it does both but it must show the graph).
[image]

Please note I have tried "Control flow factory" by DrGarbage however this wouldn't directly me allow to calculate cyclomatic complexity ( I would have to first alter the graph and then calculate it - impractical for larger examples).

[image]